# Re-index Pandas Dataframe - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and I droped some part of it. now my new data frame has not all the rows if we consider data frame as a table.
[image]

I want to change

1

2

3

11
.
.
.

to

0

1

2

3

4
.
.
.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your dataframe is `Pandas` `Dtaframe`?

Comment: @DavidDR yes it is in Pandas

Comment: Use `.reset_index()`

Comment: @IMCoins this will make another column to to the data frame. is there any way to remove the previous index?they are still there

Comment: df=df.reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: @Wen-Ben thanks it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with the optional parameter `drop=True`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A0' : list(range(10)),
        'A1' : list(range(10)),
        'A2' : list(range(10)),
        '3A' : list(range(10)),
        'A4' : list(range(10)),
        'A5' : list(range(10))
    })
print(df.head())
#    A0  A1  A2  3A  A4  A5
# 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 1   1   1   1   1   1   1
# 2   2   2   2   2   2   2
# 3   3   3   3   3   3   3
# 4   4   4   4   4   4   4

df = df.iloc[2:4]
print(df)
#    A0  A1  A2  3A  A4  A5
# 2   2   2   2   2   2   2
# 3   3   3   3   3   3   3

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
#    A0  A1  A2  3A  A4  A5
# 0   2   2   2   2   2   2
# 1   3   3   3   3   3   3
```